# ansible: how to do string interpolation in a prompt?

Tags: ansible

How can I accomplish something like this?

```
  vars_prompt:
    new_password: "new password for {{ target_username }}@{{ ansible_hostname }}?"
```

**EDIT**: based on [mgsk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3195726/mgsk) answer, I decided to simply store a default password during account creation, rather than prompt the user. My `ssh` play disables password logins anyway, so really I was just trying to prevent account lock due to not having a password entry for the user.

So I write a default password, and then use this handler to remind the operator to change it:

```
handlers:
  - name: warn default password
    debug: msg="default password installed for {{ target_username }}; be sure to change it"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vars_prompt` is run before facts gathering. I don't think you can do this, not with any standard ways. Quoting Ansible's author:

> There's been a decided emphasis in automation in Ansible and asking
>   questions at task level is not something we really want to do.
>
> However, you can still ask vars_prompt questions at play level and use
>   those variables throughout tasks.   You just can't ask questions in
>   roles.
>
> And really, that's what I would like to enforce -- if a lot of Galaxy
>   roles start asking questions, I can see that being annoying :)

See [related discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ansible-devel/prompt/ansible-devel/SMyae011_Rc/mDBPyKNolboJ) on ansible-devel mailing list.